# Add progress bar to kleeja script

Tags: javascript

I use kleeja upload script and i want to add progressbar when uploading files

I search for this a long time but i can't add this progressbar

I find many exemples with jquery but i can't add them to script

I use css style for the progressbar and javascript codes

In [This Exemple](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/10/file-upload-with-progress-bar.html) when upload complete the dowload links not appear

Please help me to solve this problem

I put these codes in header templates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
```

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>`   and this one  the index_body template

```
<!--progress bar-->
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

</div>
   <!-- /Progress bar -->
```

js and css folders http://www.gulfup.com/?fkUhK6

Comment: Could you please show some code so we can reproduce the problem?